# Best option to show word document in web page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Best option to show word document in web page, Thank you

Comment: 1) Embedding Office documents is a hellish rabbithole that you should avoid completely if it is remotely in your power. Any solution will bring you only pain. 2) Ask yourself why you don't want the document to have a URL. Is it so it can't be shared? If so, your efforts are more or less futile (they can just save the document), but you *could* generate single-use (or time-limited) URLs to prevent URL sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, if you only need to display the Word Document, but don't need to edit it, you can use Google Documents' Viewer via an `<iframe>` to display a remotely hosted `.doc`/`.docx`.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://remote.url.tld/path/to/document.doc&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

**Live Examples:**

[Google Docs Viewer](https://jsfiddle.net/7xr419yb/embedded/result/)

[Microsoft Office Viewer](https://jsfiddle.net/gcuzq343/embedded/result/)